# WinDbg (64 bit) not giving full path with lmf command

Tags: windbg

I was using WinDbg 32-bit version for quite some time, and now that I am using the 64-bit version I have a problem - lmf is not showing the full path.

Example attaching to 32-bit iexplore.exe from WinDbg (x86):

```
0:027> lmf
start    end        module name
00940000 00a06000   IEXPLORE C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
0b930000 0bdd3000   Flash10c C:\Windows\SysWow64\Macromed\Flash\Flash10c.ocx
0f860000 0fc74000   jscript9 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\jscript9.dll
5cc50000 5ccdc000   uiautomationcore C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uiautomationcore.dll
...
```

Example attaching to the same 32-bit iexplore.exe from WinDbg (x64):

```
0:021> lmf
start             end                 module name
00000000`00940000 00000000`00a06000   IEXPLORE C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
00000000`0b930000 00000000`0bdd3000   Flash    Flash.ocx   
00000000`0f860000 00000000`0fc74000   JSCRIPT9 JSCRIPT9.dll
00000000`5cc50000 00000000`5ccdc000   UIAutomationCore UIAutomationCore.DLL
...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can reproduce this in WinDbg 6.2.9200. For 32 bit programs it's still best to use 32 bit WinDbg IMHO. There's no benefit in using the 64 bit version except you want to debug the Wow64 layer.

Comment: I fully agree with Thomas' comments.  the 32 bit version of the debugger is recommended for debugging 32 bit user mode processes, except if you want to debug the wow64 layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I observed the same behavior but then was able to see the full path after running the command

`.reload -s`

Can you please give this a try!